# Problems with my menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hope the following problem won't give you a headache because it is too late for me. Anyway, I am creating a menu for my website but there is a problem: when you switch to mobile view, the menu displays at the top of the first page and when you press the hamburger icon it displays under it. It should not display at all, only when the button is pressed, you also see a weird animation when it switches to mobile view.

HTML:

```
<header>
<nav>
<ul id="nav" style="top:-15rem;">
<li class="nav_link"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li class="nav_link"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
<li class="nav_link"><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
<li class="nav_link"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>       
</ul>
<div id="bg_fix" class="shadow_on">
<a id="logo"> <span class="font">Nadia</span> <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
<div id="burger"> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> </div>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
p, h1, h2, h3, h4, li, a, button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #3d3d3d;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.font {
  font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size:30px;
}

header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index:100;
}

#bg_fix {
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}


.shadow_on {
  -webkit-box-shadow: box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em 0px rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
  -moz-box-shadow: box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em 0px rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
  box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em 0px rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
}


#nav {
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  top:-15rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding:0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em 0px rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
  -moz-box-shadow: box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em 0px rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
  box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em 0px rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
}

#nav li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px #E5E5E5 solid;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; 
}


#nav li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

#nav li:active {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#logo img {
  height: 2rem;
}

#burger {
  margin-top: 0.6rem;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  width: 1.4em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#burger span {
  display: block;
  height: 0.15rem;
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
}

#burger span:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

#burger.open span {
  background-color: #2C9FD1;
}

@media (min-width: 44em) {

header {
  -webkit-box-shadow: box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em -0.2em rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
   -moz-box-shadow: box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em -0.2em rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
    box-shadow: 0px 0.25em 0.2em -0.2em rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
    z-index: 1;
  }

nav {
  max-width: 95rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#burger {
  display: none;
}

#logo {
  float: right;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  margin-top: 0.2rem;
}

#nav {
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  transition: none;
  top: 0 !important;
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-top: 1.4rem;
  padding: 0;
}

  #nav li {
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 2.5rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.3rem 0;
  }

  #nav li {
    display: inline;
  }

  #nav li:active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }

  #nav li:hover a, #nav li:active a{
    opacity:0.5;
  }

  #bg_fix {
    transition: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    position: static;
  }

  #logo {
    margin-top: 0.1rem;
    padding: 0.7rem 0;
  }

  #logo img {
    height: 2.3rem;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
var burger = document.getElementById("burger");
var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
var navLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("nav_link");
var bgFix = document.getElementById("bg_fix");
var logo = document.getElementById("logo");

burger.onclick = function() {
    burger.classList.toggle("open");
    bgFix.classList.toggle("shadow_on");
    if (nav.style.top === "-15rem") {
        nav.style.top = "3rem";
    } else {
        nav.style.top = "-15rem";
    }
}

function markSelection() {
    burger.classList.toggle("open");
    bgFix.classList.toggle("shadow_on");
    nav.style.top = "-15rem";
}

for (i = 0, len=navLinks.length; i < len; i++) {
        navLinks[i].onclick = markSelection;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gu0j8r57/
It is hard to see here because there is only one page but you can definetely see the menu appear on the page above the menu and it's driving me crazy, you can see the weird animation when it switches to mobile view tho.

**Edit: updated jsfiddle so you can see the menu appear above it on mobile view**

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'see the menu appear on the page above the menu'? It looks ok for me

Comment: @ovokuro Please have a look at the jsfiddle and resize your screen to mobile view

Comment: Yes, it looks ok. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Maybe you could provide an image of the problem and the desired outcome.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4Gc9Q The menu should not appear above it but it should be gone until the button is pressed

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using google chrome

Comment: I cannot recreate your issue. The menu appears fine for me, in Chrome v61.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can make the menu invisible until the button is pressed?

Comment: everything looks right to me as well, I don't see the menu until the button is pressed. I do see the weird animation when you resize the window to a mobile size. but it's not likely anyone will see that since it will only be visible if someone is resizing drastically. which is almost never.

Comment: To kind of recreate the issue: switch to mobile view, refresh page and press the button two times, you will then see how it appears

Comment: switched to mobile view, refreshed, see just the NadiaLogo and humbuger button. clicked button, menu slid down into sight. clicked again and menu slide nicely back out of sight. is that not how it's supposed to work?

Comment: the NadiaLogo and humburger button stay visible and never move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to mark #nav has open. The transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out; should only happen on #nav.open

**JS:** ([jsFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/PantsStatusZero/gu0j8r57/6/))

```
var burger = document.getElementById("burger");
var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
var navLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("nav_link");
var bgFix = document.getElementById("bg_fix");
var logo = document.getElementById("logo");

burger.onclick = function() {
    burger.classList.toggle("open");
  nav.classList.toggle("open");
    bgFix.classList.toggle("shadow_on");
    if (nav.style.top === "-15rem") {
        nav.style.top = "3rem";
    } else {
        nav.style.top = "-15rem";
    }
}

function markSelection() {
    burger.classList.toggle("open");
  nav.classList.toggle("open");
    bgFix.classList.toggle("shadow_on");
    nav.style.top = "-15rem";
}

for (i = 0, len=navLinks.length; i < len; i++) {
        navLinks[i].onclick = markSelection;
}
```

**CSS:**

```
p, h1, h2, h3, h4, li, a, button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #3d3d3d;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.font {
  font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size:30px;
}

header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index:100;
}

#bg_fix {
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}


.shadow_on {
  -webkit-box-shadow: box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em 0px rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
  -moz-box-shadow: box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em 0px rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
  box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em 0px rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
}


#nav {
 // transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  top:-15rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding:0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em 0px rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
  -moz-box-shadow: box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em 0px rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
  box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em 0px rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
}

#nav.open {
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  top:-15rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding:0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em 0px rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
  -moz-box-shadow: box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em 0px rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
  box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em 0px rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
}

#nav li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px #E5E5E5 solid;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; 
}


#nav li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

#nav li:active {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#logo img {
  height: 2rem;
}

#burger {
  margin-top: 0.6rem;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  width: 1.4em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#burger span {
  display: block;
  height: 0.15rem;
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
}

#burger span:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

#burger.open span {
  background-color: #2C9FD1;
}

@media (min-width: 44em) {

header {
  -webkit-box-shadow: box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em -0.2em rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
   -moz-box-shadow: box-shadow: 0px 0.1em 0.2em -0.2em rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
    box-shadow: 0px 0.25em 0.2em -0.2em rgba(61,61,61,0.37);
    z-index: 1;
  }

nav {
  max-width: 95rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#burger {
  display: none;
}

#logo {
  float: right;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  margin-top: 0.2rem;
}

#nav {
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  transition: none;
  top: 0 !important;
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-top: 1.4rem;
  padding: 0;
}

  #nav li {
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 2.5rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.3rem 0;
  }

  #nav li {
    display: inline;
  }

  #nav li:active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }

  #nav li:hover a, #nav li:active a{
    opacity:0.5;
  }

  #bg_fix {
    transition: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    position: static;
  }

  #logo {
    margin-top: 0.1rem;
    padding: 0.7rem 0;
  }

  #logo img {
    height: 2.3rem;
  }
}
```

**HTML** *I didn't modify your html*

```
<header>
<nav>
<ul id="nav" style="top:-15rem;">
<li class="nav_link"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li class="nav_link"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
<li class="nav_link"><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
<li class="nav_link"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>       
</ul>
<div id="bg_fix" class="shadow_on">
<a id="logo"> <span class="font">Nadia</span> <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
<div id="burger"> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> </div>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work as well, I fixed it by setting <ul id="nav" style="top: to -100 in the html and changed to: if (nav.style.top === "-100rem") {
  nav.style.top = "3rem";
 } else {
  nav.style.top = "-100rem"; in the JS

Comment: I also changed the CSS and the animation on resize is gone so that is the final fix, thank you!!